# Access VCL form from DLL

Tags: delphi, dll, delphi-xe2, vcl

I have two processes A and B. Process A is a VCL forms application containing a form `TMainForm`. Process B is a DLL from which I want to remote-control this form. Something along the lines of (in process B):

```
MainForm := TMainForm.Create (nil);
MainForm.Handle := FindWindow ('TMainForm', 'MainForm Title');  // does not compile

// These two lines should remote-control the form in process A
MainForm.Edit1.Text := 'Test';
MainForm.Button1.Click;
```

Any ideas if and how this could be done?

Comment: That is not the point. I want to remote-control the application A from another application B and wanted to provide the "driver" for this in the form of a DLL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really have two separate processes, then you need inter-process communication (IPC). For example, you could make process A into an out-of-proc COM server which is consumed by process B in the manner of Office automation. That's one option of many, but they all require IPC.

However, it sounds a little like you have an executable and a DLL in the same process. In which case you have two separate instances of the VCL. Which means that you cannot pass a `TForm` object, or indeed any other VCL object between the two modules. In fact, you cannot pass any class between these two modules since you cannot share classes between modules. The `TObject` in module A is a different `TObject` from that in module B.

Your main options are:

1. Use a package instead of a DLL.
2. Use interfaces for your interop since these can be safely passed between two modules.